# XamDateTimeEditor - user should select the date from the dropdown calender only -- WPF/MVVM

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, infragistics

I have `XamDateTimeEditor` control in the XAML(code given below). Currently the user is able to type in the date or select from the calender dropdown. But I don't want the `XamDateTimeEditor` to allow any users to type in any date through keyboard, it should only be done by the dropdown using mouse.

here is the code in XAML -

```
  <igEditors:XamDateTimeEditor x:Name="xamDateTimeEditorEntryDate"
                                     AutoFillDate="MonthAndYear"
                                     IsAlwaysInEditMode="True"
                                     Mask="mm/dd/yyyy"
                                     Text="{Binding EntryDate,
                                                    Mode=TwoWay,
                                                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                                                    ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the XamDateTimeEditor's PreviewKeyDownEvent and set the e.Handled Proprty to true in the event handler. This way the user won't be able to enter anything using the Keyboard.